# Minkowski addition of the natural numbers with itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to calculate $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all natural numbers.

I believe that the answer is $\{2,3,4,5....\}=\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$

I do not know how to prove that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3, \ldots\}$. By the definition of Minkowski addition we have
$$\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{N}=\{x+y \, | \, x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } y \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$
You want to prove that
$$\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{N}=\{x+y \, | \, x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } y \in \mathbb{N}\}=\mathbb{N}-\{1\}.$$

**Claim 1).** $\mathbb{N}-\{1\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}+\mathbb{N}$.

For that, let $a \in \mathbb{N}-\{1\}$, thus $a \geq 2$. So we can write $a=(a-1)+1$, where $a-1 \geq 1$, hence a natural number. Thus we have represented $a$ as a sum of two natural numbers namely $a-1$ and $1$. This means $a \in \mathbb{N}+\mathbb{N}$.

Now you should try to prove the other set containment, namely

**Claim 2).** $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{N}-\{1\} $.

Comment: N+N⊆N−{1} :
Suppose we have a,b exists in N. a,b>=1. So a+b>=2 .Also, because a,b are Natural numbers, a+b will be also a natural number greater or equal to 2. So N+N⊆N−{1} ?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos yes that's correct.